# How can I delete/edit row in JTable and MySQL using hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, hibernate, jtable

I have a JTable displaying the content of a table in MYSQL database. I am able also to add a record in my JTable and my database.. The edit and delete operations are only possible in my JTable (the changes are not diplayed to my database). I want to add hibernate code in my buttons events so the changes can be displayed to MySQL database.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here's the class concerned:

```
  package com.hibernate.stock;

  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
  import java.awt.EventQueue;

  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
  import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

  import java.awt.GridLayout;

  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
  import javax.swing.JTextField;
  import javax.swing.JTable;
  import javax.swing.JButton;

  import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
  import org.hibernate.Session;
  import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
  import org.hibernate.Transaction;
  import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
  import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

  public class Gestion extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;
private JTextField textField_3;
private JTable table;
List biens;
int i;
PersistantBien bien = new PersistantBien();
final String columnNames[] = {"ID", "Nom", "Catégorie", "Quantité"};
final DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Gestion frame = new Gestion();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Gestion() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblId = new JLabel("ID:");
    lblId.setBounds(12, 12, 70, 15);
    contentPane.add(lblId);

    JLabel lblNom = new JLabel("nom:");
    lblNom.setBounds(12, 39, 70, 15);
    contentPane.add(lblNom);

    JLabel lblCatgorie = new JLabel("catégorie:");
    lblCatgorie.setBounds(12, 69, 70, 15);
    contentPane.add(lblCatgorie);

    JLabel lblQuantit = new JLabel("quantité:");
    lblQuantit.setBounds(12, 108, 70, 15);
    contentPane.add(lblQuantit);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(106, 10, 114, 19);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBounds(106, 37, 114, 19);
    contentPane.add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.setBounds(106, 67, 114, 19);
    contentPane.add(textField_2);
    textField_2.setColumns(10);

    textField_3 = new JTextField();
    textField_3.setBounds(106, 106, 114, 19);
    contentPane.add(textField_3);
    textField_3.setColumns(10);

    table = new JTable();
    table.setBounds(361, 50, 1, 1);
    contentPane.add(table);

    final JScrollPane tableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    tableScrollPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
            tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
            textField.setText(tableModel.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
            textField_1.setText(tableModel.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
            textField_2.setText(tableModel.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString());
            textField_3.setText(tableModel.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString());
        }
    });
    tableScrollPane.setBounds(240, 11, 198, 135);
    contentPane.add(tableScrollPane);


    JButton btnAjouter = new JButton("Ajouter");
    btnAjouter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

            SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

            Session s = sf.openSession();

            Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
            bien.setId_article(textField.getText());
            bien.setNom_article(textField_1.getText());
            bien.setCategorie(textField_2.getText());
            bien.setQuantite(textField_3.getText());

            s.save(bien);
            s.flush();
            tx.commit();
            s.close();

        }
    });
    btnAjouter.setBounds(12, 158, 117, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnAjouter);

    JButton btnEditer = new JButton("Editer");

    btnEditer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

            SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

            Session s = sf.openSession();

            Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
            DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
            tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
            tableModel.setValueAt(textField.getText(), table.getSelectedRow(), 0);
            tableModel.setValueAt(textField_1.getText(), table.getSelectedRow(), 1);
            tableModel.setValueAt(textField_2.getText(), table.getSelectedRow(), 2);
            tableModel.setValueAt(textField_3.getText(), table.getSelectedRow(), 3);

            s.save(bien);
            s.flush();
            tx.commit();
            s.close();
        }


    });
    btnEditer.setBounds(150, 158, 117, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnEditer);

    JButton btnSupprimer = new JButton("supprimer");
    btnSupprimer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

            SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

            Session s = sf.openSession();

            Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();

            DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
            tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
            tableModel.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
            SQLQuery query=s.createSQLQuery("DELETE * FROM TBiens WHERE id-article='"+textField.getText()+"'");


            s.flush();
            tx.commit();
            s.close();

        }
    });
    btnSupprimer.setBounds(303, 158, 117, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnSupprimer);

    JButton btnAfficher = new JButton("Afficher");
    btnAfficher.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try{
                Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
                cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

                SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

                Session s = sf.openSession();

                Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
                SQLQuery query=s.createSQLQuery("select * from TBiens");
                biens = query.list();
                ArrayList<Object[]> res = new ArrayList<Object[]>(biens);


                final DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
                table.setModel(tableModel);
                for (final Object[] bien : res) {
                    // Assuming each row in the biens list is a list of strings...
                    final Object[] row = bien;
                    tableModel.addRow(row);

                }

                biens.size();
                System.out.print(i);
                s.flush();
                tx.commit();
                s.close();
            }
            catch (ClassCastException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    btnAfficher.setBounds(166, 235, 117, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnAfficher);
}
```

}

Output:

[image]

Comment: *"(urgent)"*  So hire someone, urgently, and let us got on with helping people with better time management skills.

Comment: @Freek de Bruijn can you help me??

Comment: *"contentPane.setLayout(null);"* - There's a problem...

Comment: You don't need a "edit" button, by default the cells are editable...

Comment: No I'm not having problem in this. I want to implement edit and delete methods. I'll edit my question and add the output

Comment: That's great!! But how can I save changes in mysql database using hibernate?

Comment: *"No I'm not having problem in this"* - Trust me, you will...

Comment: *"how can I save changes in mysql database using hibernate"* - That depends on number of things, you could override `setValueAt` from the `TableModel` and push the changes the database there OR you could have a "save" button which pushes the changes in one go...

Comment: Can you tell more about the second method?? It's implementation.

Comment: This is pretty much the same way would save any hibernate value, expect you would be extracting the values from the `TableModel` probably via the `getValueAt(int,int)` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Editing

By default, `DefaultTableModel` will make all the cells editable, just double click the cell you want to change and it will enter "edit" model.

To save the values back to the database will depend on what approach you want to take, you could override the `setValueAt` of the `TableModel` method and push the changes when this method is called, personally, I'd add a <kbd>Save</kbd> button and push the changes as a batch

## Deleting

This is a little more difficult.  The problem is, once you remove one row, all the indices for all the other selected items will change...

A better solution would be devise a hibernate bean/data class and load this via Hibernate.  You could then use a custom implementation of the `TableModel`, extending from something like `AbstractTableModel`, which would give you management control of the content.

You would then, get all the objects that are selected (this would be a method in your custom `TableModel`, something like `getValueAt(int row)` which returned the hibernate object at the specified row) and then pass this to some kind of delete method (ie `removeValue(TBiens bean)`), firing the appropriate event notifications...

Comment: Thank's I'll try and I'll left a comment later.

Comment: Hi, I succeeded in editing and deleting data from my `JTable`. Now, I want to connect these actions with my database using hibernate. Have you any suggesstions @MadProgrammer ?

Comment: Normally what I do is pass the request (update/delete/what ever) to the "manager" or whatever is managing the process between hibernate and the request the program, allow it to perform it's action and provide a callback interface of some kind so I can obtain information about the success or failure of the operation. This allows you decouple the process (so you can reuse the management code) and means that you don't modify the table until the operation is successful and you can perform the database operation in the background

Comment: I succeeded finally in deleting and editing rows from my JTable and database :). I'll post the code. I'll focus on adding messages of control later. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeeded in deleting and editing rows from my JTable and database.
Here's the code :

```
   package com.hibernate.stock;

   import java.awt.BorderLayout;
   import java.awt.EventQueue;

   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;
   import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
   import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

   import java.awt.GridLayout;

   import javax.swing.JLabel;
   import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
   import javax.swing.JTextField;
   import javax.swing.JTable;
   import javax.swing.JButton;

   import org.hibernate.Query;
   import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
   import org.hibernate.Session;
   import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
   import org.hibernate.Transaction;
   import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
   import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

   public class Gestion extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;
private JTextField textField_3;
private JTable table;
List biens;
int i;
PersistantBien bien = new PersistantBien();
final String columnNames[] = {"ID", "Nom", "Catégorie", "Quantité"};
final DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Gestion frame = new Gestion();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Gestion() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblId = new JLabel("ID:");
    lblId.setBounds(12, 12, 70, 15);
    contentPane.add(lblId);

    JLabel lblNom = new JLabel("nom:");
    lblNom.setBounds(12, 39, 70, 15);
    contentPane.add(lblNom);

    JLabel lblCatgorie = new JLabel("catégorie:");
    lblCatgorie.setBounds(12, 69, 70, 15);
    contentPane.add(lblCatgorie);

    JLabel lblQuantit = new JLabel("quantité:");
    lblQuantit.setBounds(12, 108, 70, 15);
    contentPane.add(lblQuantit);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(106, 10, 114, 19);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBounds(106, 37, 114, 19);
    contentPane.add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.setBounds(106, 67, 114, 19);
    contentPane.add(textField_2);
    textField_2.setColumns(10);

    textField_3 = new JTextField();
    textField_3.setBounds(106, 106, 114, 19);
    contentPane.add(textField_3);
    textField_3.setColumns(10);

    table = new JTable();
    table.setBounds(361, 50, 1, 1);
    contentPane.add(table);

    final JScrollPane tableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    tableScrollPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
            tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
            textField.setText(tableModel.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
            textField_1.setText(tableModel.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
            textField_2.setText(tableModel.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString());
            textField_3.setText(tableModel.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString());
        }
    });
    tableScrollPane.setBounds(240, 11, 198, 135);
    contentPane.add(tableScrollPane);


    JButton btnAjouter = new JButton("Ajouter");
    btnAjouter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

            SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

            Session s = sf.openSession();

            Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
            bien.setId_article(textField.getText());
            bien.setNom_article(textField_1.getText());
            bien.setCategorie(textField_2.getText());
            bien.setQuantite(textField_3.getText());

            s.save(bien);
            s.flush();
            tx.commit();
            s.close();

        }
    });
    btnAjouter.setBounds(12, 158, 117, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnAjouter);

    JButton btnEditer = new JButton("Editer");

    btnEditer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

            SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

            Session s = sf.openSession();

            Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
            DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
            tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
            tableModel.setValueAt(textField.getText(), table.getSelectedRow(), 0);
            tableModel.setValueAt(textField_1.getText(), table.getSelectedRow(), 1);
            tableModel.setValueAt(textField_2.getText(), table.getSelectedRow(), 2);
            tableModel.setValueAt(textField_3.getText(), table.getSelectedRow(), 3);

            SQLQuery query=s.createSQLQuery("update TBiens "
                    + "set id_article='"+ table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),0) +"', "
                    + "nom_article= '"+ table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),1) +"', "
                    + "categorie= '"+ table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),2) +"' , "
                    + "quantite= '"+ table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),0) +"' "
                    + "where id_article = '"+ table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),0) +"'");


            query.executeUpdate();


            s.flush();
            tx.commit();
            s.close();
        }


    });
    btnEditer.setBounds(150, 158, 117, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnEditer);

    JButton btnSupprimer = new JButton("supprimer");
    btnSupprimer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

            SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

            Session s = sf.openSession();

            Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();

            DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
            tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();

            SQLQuery query=s.createSQLQuery("delete from TBiens where id_article = '"+ table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),0) +"'");
            query.executeUpdate();

            tableModel.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());

            s.flush();
            tx.commit();
            s.close();

        }
    });
    btnSupprimer.setBounds(303, 158, 117, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnSupprimer);

    JButton btnAfficher = new JButton("Afficher");
    btnAfficher.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try{
                Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
                cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

                SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

                Session s = sf.openSession();

                Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
                SQLQuery query=s.createSQLQuery("select * from TBiens");
                biens = query.list();
                ArrayList<Object[]> res = new ArrayList<Object[]>(biens);


                final DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
                table.setModel(tableModel);
                for (final Object[] bien : res) {
                    // Assuming each row in the biens list is a list of strings...
                    final Object[] row = bien;
                    tableModel.addRow(row);

                }

                biens.size();
                System.out.print(i);
                s.flush();
                tx.commit();
                s.close();
            }
            catch (ClassCastException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    btnAfficher.setBounds(166, 235, 117, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnAfficher);
}
   }
```